# UITableviewを開いた時にセルをピョコッと横方向に移動させるアニメーションを実現したい

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

例に示しているのはamazonのアプリですがこれと同じようにコードでセルを少しスライドさせて
元に戻すアニメーションを実現したいです。
UIScrollViewであればcontentOffsetを変更すればオフセット量をコントロールできますが、
UITableviewCellの左右のスワイプ動作をアニメーションで表示するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか?

サンプルのアニメーションではswiftの本を表示させていますが、できればobjective-cでお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

カスタムセルにUIScrollViewがのっているだけです。スワイプではなくパン（ドラッグ）です。

もし、カスタムセルの作成や制御の知識がまるでないのならそれを学ぶ必要がありますし、それが備わっているならUIScrollViewが使用されていると分かるだけで十分でしょう。右方向へのスクロール時に表示される関連項目が随時追加されるのをみると、ページングではなくデリゲートを介して半端なオフセットに対し手動で表示状態を修正したり、コンテンツの横幅を変更していると思われます。

Comment: カスタムセルを使ってるのですね。
UITableViewのeditActionsForRowAtIndexPathやcommitEditingStyleでセルを左右にドラッグできるようになるので、てっきりその状態を取得、または設定できるような仕組みがあるものと思い込んでおりました。
どうりで、いくら調べても見つからないわけですね。

カスタムセルにscrollViewを乗せるだけであれば枯れた手法なのでいくらでも味付けできそうです。
ありがとうございました！